# Trigger a button via SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: workflow, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am trying to trigger a button via SuiteScript 2.0 that was placed on a transaction form by a workflow. Is this possible to perform? As an example, a workflow places a sales order on hold (pending approval). A user would then select approve or reject and the workflow would move on. I would like to place a script to run every 30 minutes that would check certain parameters. If the parameters are met, then trigger the approve button that was placed on the previous workflow.
All help is greatly appreciated!
Brad

Answer (score 0):

Search help for nlapiTriggerWorkflow. The should be workflow action id for the button created by the workflow, you can use that.